# Dragging and dropping onto a listview, how to get the item position that was dropped on

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a list of items, when the item is dragged it can be dropped onto an item in another listview of items.

I already have the id of the item being dragged, I need to somehow figure out which item in the listview the item was dropped onto so that I can get the object from the adapter for that position.

Here is my current attempt at this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
                ClipData data = event.getClipData();
                View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
                Integer position = listView.getPositionForView(droppedView);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ID: " + data.getItemAt(0).getText() + " Pos " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is unfortunately not working as the event.getLocalState() returns the view from where it was initially dragged not the one that it is being dragged onto.

The view v appears to be the FrameLayout of the entire app so also not useful.

I'm thinking that there may be some data within the DragEvent that I'm missing, or is drag and drop just not supported for dropping items onto a listview?

I believe part of the issue is that the fragment itself is capturing the drag, but it is not passing it through to the listview items, if there was some way of passing through the drag to the children views it may work.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end my idea about passing the drag down to the listview seems to be somewhat correct, in my parent fragment I do the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        listView.onDragEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
```

You also need to add a drag listener to the listview itself like so:

```
listView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And then within the **adapter** for the listview, pass the fragment as a parameter in the constructor (I believe getCallingActivity() would do this job for activities), and do the following:

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
                        parentFragment.performAction(event, item.getId());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The end result is that you can get the item as you normally would with a listview adapter as well as the DragEvent which you can use to grab the ClipData.